# The operation has timed out ~ System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, http, web

The operation has timed out ~ System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

doing a load testing of http server with multiple requests per second. after few hundred successful requests and responses, new request get stuck and after the timeout value is achieved(timeout = 30 second) request timeout exception is thrown.
all the solutions i found was regarding closing the stream properly which I hope I am doing.
Any help on resolving the timeout problem would be appreciated. thanks.

```
  using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = client.GetRequestStream())
  {
                    requestStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);

                    requestStream.Close();

                }
```

Comment: What did you expect? If you're loadtesting your server, it's quite possible that at some point it can't handle any new requests. Hence timeouts may occur on the client side.

Comment: this scenario occurs when I increase the requests per second, almost 15 requests per second. on 5 requests per second the server can handle thousands of requests without any timeouts.

Comment: is there any limit to the simultaneous requests that httpserver can process/handle?

Comment: on another better machine server can handle the load of 15 requests per second. without timeouts. so I am not sure where the problem is.